# Angular 4 : best practice for accessing large object data in multiple components - RESTful JAVA back

Tags: angular, rest, restful-architecture

I would like to know what is the best way to go in a RESTful Angulr4/Java application, when dealing with large objects and sub-objects.

1. Get all data (including all data from its sub objects) in the parent component using that component's service and then sharing this via property binding and @input to all his child components.
2. Get only the main object in the parent component, passing it via property binding to its child and then let each child call via REST request everything it needs.
3. Any better solution...?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data shouldn't be retrieved/stored in components. Services are for dealing with data. A service can be injected into a component, which could pass the data to its children via binding. If a piece of data is large, you may want to cache the data in a singleton service, so when a component makes a second retrieve for a large data object, you can check the cache first, and if the data is there, don't hit the server - return the data from the cache.

Also, components can also be categorized as smart and presentational. Smart components are the ones that have app logic, use services and pass the data to the presentational components via binding.

The presentational components are for UI rendering and have no or minimal app logic. They may not even know anything about the services and can use @Input and @Output params for communication with the outside world.

Having said that, even the separation into presentational and smart components is not a clear cut. Your app may use injectable services for the passing data instead of using binding in the presentational component.

So there is no general answer to your question. It depends on specifics of your app.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for your prompt reply.